# How to check if a function exists when it is defined in a different file?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have written some library code to deal with drag-and-drop. I would like to use this library (which defines some `CustomEvents`) in several projects*. The handlers for these events may or may not be defined in each project.
So, I have, for example,

```
if (typeof onDropped === 'function') {
      const event = new CustomEvent("dropped", { detail: this.el.id });
      this.el.addEventListener(
          "dropped",
          onDropped(event),
          false
      );
      this.el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Now, if I define `onDropped` in the same file, everything works as expected:

```
var onDropped = function(e)
{
    console.log(e.type + ' handled; data: ' + e.detail)
}
```

and if `onDropped` isn't defined there's no problem, the event isn't created.

But `onDropped` needs to be defined in *another file* which will be using the library - in which case it isn't found by the library. I have tried using import/export but that doesn't work if the function hasn't been defined (and anyway the library file wouldn't really know where to import it from).

I have also tried `if (window.onDropped)` instead of `if (typeof onDropped === 'function')`but without success.

[edit]
I have added [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbdqksgL/) to show that the CustomEvent creation (and use of it) works fine when the handler is in the same file. But with a jsfiddle I cannot show it failing to find the handler when it is in a different file.

*the projects will all be using [vue3.js](https://vuejs.org/), but I'm unsure if this is relevant to the solution.

Comment: it is quite confusing, can you prepare a codesandbox or something like that so that everyone can understand problem?

Comment: you're passing `onDropped` incorrectly - you're invoking it and then passing the result to `addEventListener`, instead of passing a reference to the function.

Comment: `if (onDropped) this.el.addEventListener("dropped",onDropped);`

Comment: @lehanh, I have now added a jsfiddle, see edited post.

Comment: @Alnitak, I thnk the construction of the eventListener is correct; it works as can be seen in the sample I have just uploaded, So not sure what you mean.

Comment: @quilkin I can assure you it isn't.  You'll see in your jsfiddle that it prints "handled" immediately when `createEvent` is called, and _not_ as a result of the `dispatchEvent` call.  You can see this if you comment out the call to `dispatchEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was making things much more complicated than they need be. I didn't read enough about dispatching events (and/or the example I was using was more complex than I needed). The following seems to fine:

In the library:

```
const event = new CustomEvent('dropped', { detail: {from:droppedFrom.id, to:droppedTo.id }});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and in the library user's code:

```
document.addEventListener('dropped', (e) => {
  console.log('dropped from ' + e.detail.from + ' to ' + e.detail.to);
})
```

although I'd be grateful for any further comments!